# Is it possible to query ALL ROWS in the child portion of a parent to child query?

Tags: soql, isdeleted

Executing the apex below does not return any deleted Task records even though the deleted records exist. If I query Tasks alone then the deleted tasks are returned. Does this mean it's not possible to query deleted or archived related records from the parent? I've been struggling to find documentation on limits of using ALL ROWS in a query...

```
for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT id,
                       (SELECT id, isdeleted FROM Tasks)
                        FROM Opportunity
                        ALL ROWS]) {
    for (Task t : opp.Tasks) {
        system.debug(t.isdeleted);       
    }                    
}
```

Comment: I assume you can't apply the ALL ROWS in the nested SELECT...?

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Do you mean adding it made the query work, or that adding it was invalid?

Comment: Adding it to the nested query was invalid.